# Automatic Resizing background with Text and annimated gif imbedded

Tags: css

Please take a look at [troop981.com](http://www.troop981.com/default/):

The Mountains.jpg with the eagle.gif and the editable text looks like it hangs over the edge of page when viewing on different sized monitors or when zoomed in on.

I want to make the Mountains.jpg, and the Text on top of the jpg re-size the width and height in proportion to the users view.

The code below is the HTML of the page. I'd appreciate any help since I dont know anything about HTML or CSS and the person who built the site is no longer with us.

```
<style>
    .background_image
    {
    background:url(http://www.troop981.com/default/portals/0/Tatra_Mountains_Panorama_01.jpg);      /* image to display */
    width:1602px;                     /* width of image */
    height:332px;                    /* height of image */
    overflow:hidden;                 /* so div won't change size */
    }
    .eagle_image
    {
    height: 222px; /* use the actual height of the eagle gif */
    width: 250px; /* use the actual width of the eagle gif */
    background:url(http://www.troop981.com/default/portals/0/0049.gif) no-repeat; /* use your eagle filename */
    position: absolute; top: 50px;    /* adjust these to see the eagle move to where you want */
    left: 40px;                               /* ditto from above */
    }
    .text_properties
    {
    padding-left:2px;                /* position of text in inner div */
    padding-top:2px;                 /* position of text in inner div */
    padding-right:2px;               /* position of text in inner div */
    padding-bottom:2px;              /* position of text in inner div */
    color:darkgreen;                   /* text color */
    font-size:40px;                  /* font size */
    font-weight:bold;                /* font weight */
    font-family:script;               /* font family */
    margin-left:400px;                 /* left position of text */
    margin-top:50px;                 /* top position of text */
    }
</style>
<div class="background_image">
<div class="eagle_image"></div>
<div class="text_properties">Congratulations to Patrick Guilfoy &ndash; Troop 981&rsquo;s 104th Eagle Scout</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to downscale the background image? I think it's better to not downscale that, but just to make the text scalable when you view the page in a smaller size.

Try to change the .background_image with this:

```
.background_image
    {
    background:url(http://www.troop981.com/default/portals/0/Tatra_Mountains_Panorama_01.jpg);      /* image to display */
    width:100%;                     /* width of image */
    height:332px;                    /* height of image */
    overflow:hidden;                 /* so div won't change size */
    }
```

This way it will just reduce the width of the background image (not the height) and the tekst will adjust to the size of the screen.

Comment: Roy, Thank you very much! this now looks better. This solved the picture overflowing the page by the width. The text then returns to a second line in the image when viewed on a smaller screen and actually starts to overlap the first line a bit. I suppose I can set that up as two lines to begin with or is there an easy way to make that scalable also?

Comment: You could set a line-height. "line-height: 48px;" (without quotes in the ".text_properties"). Your text is 40px, this way you'll get 4px margin on the top and 4 px margin on the bottom. You can play around with it if you're not completely satisfied. I'm afraid though that the eagle will cover up your text. So try to set the text align to the right. Maybe that will look better. So try to add "text-align: right;" (without quotes) in the .text_properties